# Vue js dynamic v-model for form which is rendered with v-for

Tags: dynamic, vuejs2, v-model

I have 1 check box group and 9 radio button groups, and i need v-model  for each group but i do not know how to put 9 differed data properties there.

My data looks like this:

data() {
return{

servicesId: [],
personId: '',
incomeId:'',
extraIncomeId: '',
pdvId: '',
paymentId: '',
clientId: '',
cashRegisterId: '',
eBankingId: '',

}
}

In template is like this:

```
 <div  v-for="data in formData" :key="data.id">
  <h5>{{data.question_text}}</h5>
  <div class="form-check" v-for="text_o in data.question_options" :key="text_o.id">
    <input  class="form-check-input"   
     :type="data.question_type.type" 
     :value="text_o.id" :id="text_o.id"
     v-model="[HERE GOES "9 "data props"]">

   <label  class="form-check-label"  :key="text_o.id" :for="text_o.id"> {{text_o.option_text} 
   </label>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Here is part of (because it is long, i can post everything from it if you want)formData array:

```
   {
        "id": 1,
        "question_type_id": 1,
        "title": "new ent",
        "question_text": "Planirate da se bavite:",
        "created_at": "2021-10-12T13:42:17.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-10-12T13:42:17.000000Z",
        "question_options": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "question_id": 1,
                "option_text": "Uslugama",
                "price": 40,
                "created_at": "2021-10-12T13:44:40.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-10-12T13:44:40.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "question_id": 1,
                "option_text": "Trgovinom",
                "price": 60,
                "created_at": "2021-10-12T13:46:53.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-10-12T13:46:53.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "question_id": 1,
                "option_text": "Proizvodnjom",
                "price": 80,
                "created_at": "2021-10-12T13:47:22.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-10-12T13:47:22.000000Z"
            }
        ],
        "question_type": {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "checkbox",
            "created_at": "2021-10-12T13:40:17.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-10-12T13:40:17.000000Z"
        }
    }

Thanks.
```

Comment: Can you show us formData array?

Comment: I have added  part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your values to be a part of data, you can create an object that will contain your form data, like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    formValue: {
      servicesId: [],
      personId: "",
      incomeId: "",
      extraIncomeId: "",
      pdvId: "",
      paymentId: "",
      clientId: "",
      cashRegisterId: "",
      eBankingId: "",
    },
  }
}
```

after adding that object, just add a name to your form data object like this:

```
  formData: [
    {
      id: 1,
      question_type_id: 1,
      title: "new ent",
      question_text: "Planirate da se bavite:",
      created_at: "2021-10-12T13:42:17.000000Z",
      updated_at: "2021-10-12T13:42:17.000000Z",
      name: "servicesId",   <-- modified part
      question_options: [...]
    }
  ]
```

and now you can use that name to dynamically access your formValue object which is a part of data:

```
 <div v-for="data in formData" :key="data.id">
      <h5>{{ data.question_text }}</h5>
      <div
        class="form-check"
        v-for="text_o in data.question_options"
        :key="text_o.id"
      >
        <input
          class="form-check-input"
          :type="data.question_type.type"
          :value="text_o.id"
          :id="text_o.id"
          v-model="formValue[data.name]"   <-- modified part
        />

        <label class="form-check-label" :key="text_o.id" :for="text_o.id">
          {{ text_o.option_text }}
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this approach helps you, you will have your values in data, they won't be there as separate properties, but they will be a part of a wrapper object named `formValue`

Comment: Chekboxes are not working (they are selected all at once), radios are working. But i need that ids at data(){return{HERE}}.
I'm thinking to create table with those names an loop through it.

Comment: I've edited my answer, take a look.

Comment: Yeah that looks nice, thanks.

Comment: It is working, thank you very much, I would do it a lot worse :D

Comment: You are welcome. If it resolved your problem please accept it as an answer :)